# How to make image asset fit all sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, image

My view had a background image which was shown full screen. But I couldn't make it fit all iPhone sizes as following:

> 640*960, 640*1136, 750*1334, 1080*1920

I tried to differ them by name.

> icon@1x.png, icon-568h@2x.png, icon-667h@2x.png, icon@3x.png

And it looks like this in Asset:
[image]

But still not working. I know it's easy for Launch Image but that image is not. Please help me with this.